# Is it possible that Ruby Marshallng may work differently with different versions of ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I need to send complex object(https://github.com/nepalez/ebay_api - EbayAPI object may have big amount of data) to sidekiq. So, marshaling looks like a good solution. What I am afraid of: Is it possible that Ruby Marshaling may work differently with different versions of ruby?

So, one day I will update ruby version, and due load marshaled object the original object would be not the same, as before marshaled, is it possible?

Comment: Are you going to store the marshaled data permanently somewhere or does it just exist temporarily as long as the Sidekiq worker runs?

Comment: I would totally expect that.

Comment: @Alex: You mean:Two different versions of MRI Ruby? I know for sure that the marshalling  format is not compatible between the MRI Ruby version we are using and the JRuby version we are also using. I could also imagine that, for instance due to the fact that the encoding is also stored in the Marshalled format, strings marshalled for MRI Ruby 1.x are not compatible for 2.x. Since we don't know what else will be included in the future, I would certainly not assume upwards compatibility with `Marshal`.

Comment: The doc for the [Marshal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Marshal.html) module states (second paragraph), "Marshaled data has major and minor version numbers stored along with the object information. In normal use, marshaling can only load data written with the same major version number and an equal or lower minor version number."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Note, however, that the binary format used by Marshal.dump and Marshal.load is version dependent, and newer versions of Ruby are not guaranteed to be able to read marshalled objects written by older versions of Ruby." (The Ruby Programming Language, David Flanagan and Yukuhiro Matsumoto, page 83).

Answer (score -1):

I'd recently a problem with Rails cache during migration from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4. App was unable to read AR models from the cache (same time simpler objects like hashes, array worked well). But ruby was the same.

So please pay attention that some issues might happen, so better for you to try.

I suggest marshaled object to save in file with one version of ruby and read with another.